# Integrate Quickbooks Online with Sharepoint 2010 app

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to integrate my sharepoint app to Quickbooks Online thru' IPP Devkit libraries.

My question is can it be done?? as i have seen that ti install IPP Devkit libraries, we need .Net framework 4.0, but as sharepoint supports only upto .Net Framework 3.5

Can anyone help me on this, If Yes how can we do that & If no, is there any other alternate to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Deepthi.
The SDK uses 4.0 to call the QuickBooks REST APIs, it has nothing to do with how you integrate with Sharepoint after the fact.

However, you should read the FAQs on the type of apps you can build using the QuickBooks API
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0058_FAQ

thanks
Jarred